# Wordpress Ajax deeplink gives 404

Tags: ajax, wordpress, url, http-status-code-404

**Hi Folks,**

my first post here, thanks for any help i got already throught reading before.

I am working on a wordpress projekt. And it seems i am missing the overview on my problem. 
I use ajax to recieve additional product data. http:url/product/additional_ajax_data...

This works fine, except direct call of the ajax urls. Direct call of a ajax url gives 
a 404 not found.

Please dont give instructions like: add 200 ok to header... Cause the project will 
consist of some thousand pages and work arounds like this are a no go...

**Aditional infos:  the urls have no ajax hash tag...** And the content will dynamicly loaded depending on last url fragment

## I found the solution:

To prevent Wordpress of 404 when calling a ajax url directly, add rewrite endpoints to the system.

You can follow the post from Jon Cave on Wordpress:

http://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/

Works also on custom post_types and custom taxonomys, keep an eye on the type for wich you want to register a custom endpoint rewrite (that may depends on your options from your post type, page type etc...).

Comment: At the moment i check the current url through a document rdy function like this... But i guess it is already to late to have effect...

Comment: <code>function check_current_url(  ) 
{

  var currentAnchor = document.location;
  currentAnchor = String( currentAnchor );
  urls = currentAnchor.split("/");
 if ( urls.length == 6 )
 {
   url = urls[5];

  currentAnchor = switch_anchor( url );
  loadContent( currentAnchor );  
 } 

}<code>

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that url is correct and file is there, check if permissions on file are not too strict. Also check .htaccess to make sure it doesn't black certain file extensions to be loaded directly

Comment: Thanks for the answer  

There is no file, i load the content dynamicly depending on the last url fragment...

Comment: But this could be the way, adding templates to request data types... Over .htaccess rewrites...

Comment: Found a simple soloution with adding a rewrite endpoint to prevent 404: http://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/